# How do you load a url in a UIWebView

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I just started creating a simple application in Xamarin C#. 
I have two views : first view have a "login" button and a second view have a webView inside.
I have created the modal segue which connect those two views and my question is :

 **How can I get if second view is showing it's content and it's webView can load this url : "http://vk.com" ?**

Comment: Please give your questions meaningful titles.

Comment: @Jason your title is not meaningful TOO. The question was something like : How can I get if second view is showing it's content...and it's web view can load *url*

Answer (score 1):

Well, at first, you need to add two views. 
On the first view place a button. Connect this button to a second view(create a modal segue)

On the second view you can place a label or something different, it doesn't matter.
Zoom out your storyboard(in Xcode storyboard editor, "-" icon), select and set the second view class, for example, "view_two". Save and return to Xamarin Studio. Restart Xcode. Now, **in Xamarin Studio select Your class file(in this case - view_two.cs)** and open it. Then, insert this code in the "center" of the document :

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            this.webView_login.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl ("http://vk.com")));
        }
```

Comment: you haven't even answered your own question - specifically how to load a url in a webview.  What does UIAlertView have to do with what you asked?

Comment: @Jason Well, it was not a problem to load a webpage to webView. The problem was that I don't knew that I was need to write "public override voidDidLoad()"

Answer (score 0):

In the View's ViewDidLoad method:

```
string url = "http://vk.com";
webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
```

See also: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/web_view/load_a_web_page/

Answer (score 0):

This below piece will will help.

```
        UIWebView webView = new UIWebView(View.Bounds);
        View.AddSubview(webView);
        var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var yourWonFolderPath = Path.Combine(documents, "YourWonFolder");
        var localDocUrl = Path.Combine(yourWonFolderPath, TicketInfo.TicketNumber + ".pdf");
        webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false)));
        webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```